# SPL autoloader class auto creating new objects

Tags: php, eval, spl

I am going to invoke creating new objects, via SPL autoloader.
But i couldnt create new object of class which was already included by loader. Dunno why, but i dont want to use eval, where i can find answer? Sorry for my bad english..

nothing strange simple code:

```
class load
{  public static function init()
    {return spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, "hook"));}
    public static function quit()
    {return spl_autoload_unregister(array(__CLASS__, "hook"));}
    public static function hook($class)
    {   echo "CLASS IS:$class<br>";
        $lnk=PATH . str_replace("_", "/", $class) . ".php";
        ob_start();
        require $lnk;

        ob_clean();

    }
}
```

Comment: Show all the relevant code. Else it's impossible to tell where your problems lie.

Comment: That code is indeed strange. If you feel the need to capture output, it's likely that you are not using class scripts as intended. Additionally you don't close the opened output buffer levels. -- Explain what the eval idea is supposed to be about.

Comment: need to add ob_ end_ clean()?

Comment: im using sub dirs, thats why here is a replace

Answer (score 0):

Autoloaders aren't for creating new objects; they're for including new *classes*.  Once the class exists, the autoloader doesn't need to load it again -- in fact, it couldn't without triggering a fatal error (since classes can't be defined twice).  Therefore, it won't run the class file that you presumably also coded to have some other side effects.

If you want a new object, just create it with `new ClassYouWantToCreatAnInstanceOf`.  If the class doesn't exist yet, the autoloader will try to load it.  But the class file generally shouldn't be creating instances itself, for the very reason you're seeing.

Comment: It means that it is impossible to creating object into spl loader? even via eval? or mayble some other methods, i need it very strong(

Comment: What you need is to use the right tool for the job.  Why do you want a class loader to create a new object?  What is the *real* goal?